# Bind a custom type property to a custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am trying to bind to a user control a property of a custom type (in our exemple, let's call it `DataContextOne`). This custom type is composed of two strings.

I then have a user control to which I want to bind this custom type.

The weird thing is that if I put in my control 2 string properties and then try to bind each string from my custom type, it worked. But when I create just a `DataContextOne` property in my Custom Control and try to bind to it, nothing happens (= null in the user control).

Here is my code

## DataContextOne

```
public class DataContextOne : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string _title;
    public string Title 
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set
        {
            if (_title != value)
            {
                _title = value;
                TitleModified = _title + " modified";
                RaisePropertyChanged("Title");
            }
        }
    }

    private string _titlemodified;
    public string TitleModified
    {
        get { return _titlemodified; }
        set
        {
            if (_titlemodified != value)
            {
                _titlemodified = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("TitleModified");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

## Binding that works

#### UserControl

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{

    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        (Content as FrameworkElement).DataContext = this;
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Text",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(MyUserControl),
            null);

    public string TextModified
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextModifiedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextModifiedProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextModifiedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "TextModified",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(MyUserControl),
            null);
}
```

#### Main Window

code behind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Random Rnd = new Random();
    DataContextOne dtone = new DataContextOne();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dtone.Title = Rnd.Next().ToString();
        DataContext = dtone;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dtone.Title = Rnd.Next().ToString();
    }
}
```

xaml:

```
<local:MyUserControl Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Title, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" TextModified="{Binding TitleModified, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

## Binding that doesn't work

#### User Control

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{

    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        (Content as FrameworkElement).DataContext = this;
    }

    public DataContextOne dtone 
    {
        get { return (DataContextOne)GetValue(dtoneProperty); }
        set { SetValue(dtoneProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty dtoneProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "dtone",
            typeof(DataContextOne),
            typeof(MyUserControl),
            null);

}
```

#### Main Window

Code Behind (note that I bind `this`)

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Random Rnd = new Random();
    DataContextOne dtone = new DataContextOne();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dtone.Title = Rnd.Next().ToString();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dtone.Title = Rnd.Next().ToString();
    }
}
```

xaml

```
<local:MyUserControl Grid.Row="1" dtone="{Binding dtone, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="0,31,200,169"/>
```

I don't understand what is missing. For me it is the same thing with just a custom type that encapsulate the strings on the second version, so why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{Binding dtone}` tries to bind to `dtone` property of `DataContext`, which is `MainWindow`. There is no `dtone` property in `MainWindow` class, only a private field, and you cannot bind to fields.

Possible solutions:

- make `dtone` a property
- or change `DataContext = this` to `DataContext = dtone` and `{Binding dtone}` to `{Binding}`

**Update**

Probably unrelated, but there seems to be no reason to have a `dtone` property in `MyUserControl`. Why not simple

```
<local:MyUserControl Grid.Row="1" DataContext="{Binding dtone}" />
```

without trying to set `DataContext` manually in `MyUserControl` constructor?

Comment: So i changed to `public DataContextOne dtone { get; set; }` and then in my `public MainWindow()` I put `dtone = new DataContextOne();` but it give the same result

Comment: Also you should probably modify XAML of your UserControl (all bindings are relative to the control, and since it does not contain `Text` property, you must write `{Binding dtone.Text}`).

Comment: Thanks max, it was exactly the issue. I didn't knew about the need for a property and for the XAML I don't know why I didn't changed it :)